# How to disable showing a layer while changing resolution (e.g. zoom animation) in OL3?

Tags: openlayers-3

While changing zoom factors for a map, its layers appear stretched with the latest available data, i.e. lower resolution tiles, images, etc.
Is it possible to disable this effect? I would like to have the layer shown only after its "loadend", but the layer's data will be loaded only if it's visible...

I've digged into the rendering workflow, but it's nto easy to find a consistent way to obtain it for all the renderers.

Comment: Were you able to solve this, giohappy?  I'm looking for how to do this too in ol3.

Comment: Nope, I haven't worked on that.